# Accidently Overwrites my mac partition for ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery, mac, boot-partition

While trying to dual boot my mac with reFInd, I accidently overwrites my mac partition. Is there any means of recovering the partition because I'm yet to backup some important files?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by overwriting your mac partition? I don't know rEFInd provides a feature to erasing a partition.

Comment: I just noticed that I can't access the mac partition and it boots straight to ubuntu and when I checked the "About This Computer" on ubuntu, It's taking my whole hard disk space.

Comment: You probably let Ubuntu use the entire disk during the installation. If that is the case, there is probably no going back. Chance of recovering any data is going to be a painful process. Most HFS+ recovery tool runs on Windows and they normally help to recover deleted partition or deleted files, no when it  is overwritten by another installation.

Comment: Anyway this is probably off topic now, as you need to recover your files originally from the HFS+ partition. Use google, hopefully you can find a tools that can help, https://www.google.com/search?q=hfs+plus+data+recovery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b

Comment: Ok I've installed hfsplus with "sudo apt-get install -y hfsplus" . Any idea on how to use it for recovery?

Comment: Not sure why you think that will help, it won't. Re-post your question to https://apple.stackexchange.com, describe that you have overwritten the MacOS partition with Ubuntu and need to recover some files from the original MacOS partition.